# Custom Validation messages spring not being displayed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am currently using the following environment:

- Netbeans 8
- Jdk 1.7
- Spring 4
- Hibernate 5.0.1
- Bean validator 1.1

I have got the following files:

- Servlet configuration (Spring):

  ```
          <context:component-scan base-package="mz.co.hypervision.web" />

          <mvc:annotation-driven />

         <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
        </bean>
  ```

Student class:

```
   public class Student {
   @NotNull(message = "{age.notnull}")
   private Integer age;
   private String name;
   private Integer id;

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public Integer getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }
}
```

Message properties file:

Location: SpringTest\build\web\WEB-INF\classes

```
# To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
# To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.

age.notnull=The age of the student may not be null
```

**UPDATED**

Controller code:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import mz.co.hypervision.domain.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "student", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") @Valid Student student, 
   BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

      if(result.hasErrors()) {

          return "student";
      } else {
        model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
        model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
        model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

        return "result";
      }
   }
}
```

Please check below that the message appears as {age.notnull}:

[Image with the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wxp7.png)

Please assist in figuring out why it is not working, as per my view I have followed every step to make it happen

Comment: Are you getting any errors or an unexpected message.Provide more details

Comment: Hi ekem,there is no error message, the custom validation message simply does not appear when the age is null i simply see: "age.notnull"

Comment: I suspect your Controller logic. It might not be adding the validation errors to the model.Post your controller code

Comment: I have edited the post with the controller code and with the situation in the image

Comment: From your setup everything seems to be ok.Test on your view whats displayed for <spring:message code="age.notnull"/> by importing the spring tag library if you are using JSTL. Validation logic is working but message resolution seems to be the issue.Also consider rebuilding your project so it can pick any changes to your messages prperties file

Comment: Hi Ekem, It was an issue with the messages.properties file that was not in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding the messages.properties file to the java classpath